# cannot fetch firestore data from react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Below are my security rules for firestore database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my code to fetch data:

```
fetchUsers=async()=>{
        const db=firebase.firestore();
        const response=db.collection('users');
        const data=await response.get();
        data.doc.forEach(item=>{console.log(item)})
    }
```

`users` is the name of the collection in the firestore. It has one document.

But I get an error on console:

```
Cannot read forEach property of undefined
```

what am I missing? Please help me to find the solution of above problem.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You must use either of the following

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function YYY(props){
    const { id } = useParams();
    db.collection('users').doc(id).get().then((doc) =>{console.log(doc.data())})
}
```

Or just use `onSnapshot`

```
db.collection('users').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. But the code I have shown in the question was taken from a tutorial. why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because there is no `doc` property for a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). The property which returns an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot` is named [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs).

So you need to do `data.docs.forEach(...);`

You probably made a typo while copying the code from the tutorial.